# Changing the style of the bibliography header

Tags: bibtex

I use bibtex to generate bibliography. How do I make the title of the bibliography have a custom text, size and alignment?

**Edit:**

I use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` and `\bibliographystyle{gost2008}` which is a custom bibliography style made by someone else.

Also I use babel package for language support.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %% add bibliography to table of contents

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% TEXT OF MY DOCUMENT %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bibliographystyle{gost2008}
\bibliography{main_bib,extra_bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you creating the bibliography (i.e. creating a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) for us)?

Answer (score 2):

I would advice *against* changing the style of elements mid-document.

[image: spiderfaceBibHeading]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %% add bibliography to table of contents

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Wombats are cool}
\cite{doody}
\renewcommand{\tocbibname}{\sffamily\small Proof of Coolness}
\bibliographystyle{gost2008}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\end{document}
```

Another example, changing alignment as well.

[image: spiderfaceMara]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %% add bibliography to table of contents

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Maras are cute}
Look at them, they really are.~\cite{doody}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Proof of Cuteness}
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\centering\bfseries\color{BrickRed}}{\thesection.}{\enspace}{}{}
\bibliographystyle{gost2008}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could write a more general answer where it would be clear which command does what?
Also, this does not change the alignment of the header.

Comment: @spiderface You can use package `titlesec` and change the appearance of sections just before the bibligraphy. Changing the name is one thing, slipping in a font command another, but huge changes are harder; especially if you want a generic answer as this stuff is highly dependant on the packages in use. For example, that answer will not work if package `tocbibind` is not used and on the other hand, an answer for not using `tocbibind` won't work anymore if the package is loaded. It is more complicated than you might think.

Comment: I achieved the same result with
`\renewcommand\refname{\sffamily \normalsize Proof of coolness}`
which does not depend on `tocbibind`.

I also tried to center the header with 
`\renewcommand\refname{\sffamily \normalsize \begin{center}{Proof of coolness}\end{center}}`

but it didn't compile.

Comment: @spiderface see update.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but mere inclusion of `titlesec` made the section numbers disappear through the entire document.

Comment: Apparently, inclusion of `[block]` into `\titleformat` like this `\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{\thesection.}{1em}{}{}` fixes missing numbering for some reason. This line should be included before all the sections. Also `\enspace` gives a compilation error, so I repalced it with `1em`.

Comment: @spiderface Last `titlesec` update brought up some bugs, as you can see.

Comment: How can you make sure that the style change is *not* reflected on the table of contents?

Comment: @goz Please ask a new question